# Web page login with python failure or not?

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to login to the site www.dsbmobile.de. It uses a form (`<form name="form1" method="post" action="./Login.aspx" id="form1">`), so I do the following:

```
import requests
url="https://www.dsbmobile.de/Login.aspx"
values={'txtUser':'XXXuserXXX','txtPass':'XXXpasswordXXX'}
r=requests.post(url,data=values)
s=requests.get(url,r.cookies,auth=(values['txtUser'], values['txtPass']))
```

Both r and s yield a successful response (200), and I get a cookie. However, the resulting page still shows the login page, whereas if I login manually, I get a different page.

Why does the automated login fail?

Most likely this is a duplicate question, but I have tried more than 20 other suggestions from stackoverflow and have failed so far.

Comment: You should pass `values` to the `data` parameter, and use `requests.Session`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It does also not work. I analyzed the page source and it uses javascript. I also looked into other packages to help me. E.g. MechanicalSoup's FAQ states: "If the website relies on JavaScript, then you probably need a fully-fledged browser. Selenium may help you there, but it’s a far heavier solution than MechanicalSoup." So I guess, with python-request I will most likely not succeed? Correct?

Comment: Not exactly. If you inspect the data that get posted you'll notice that there are more fields that you have to submit (__VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, etc). The bad news is that those fields are dynamic, which means that you have to scrape them with `bs4` or `lxml`. Or you could try `selenium`.

Comment: I went ahead with `selenium` and it worked within a rather short time -- compared with what I did with `requests`. It requires a much larger memory footprint, though, which will be not so nice on the intended platform (RaspberryPi). Thanks for the help!